# Requring all the files in a directory nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, directory

The topic may seem to be duplicate. Read it completely

I know there are multiple packages available in nodejs to require all the files in a directory.

But I am in a research to require all the files in a folder and use the variables and functions which are exported in each js file. Need to perform this just by requiring the directory name.

For example,

```
var files = require("./folder");
```

The folder may contain some files like

> File1.js, File2.js, File3.js

I want to use all the variables and functions which are exported in all the js files.

I think there might be some way in the "Package.json" file.

But I am not expert in "Package.json".

Can anyone help me to figure out the senario?

Comment: Package-node.js http://browsenpm.org/package.json

Answer (score 2):

Could you just make an index.js file with the modules and just require that.

From the docs http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders

It is convenient to organize programs and libraries into self-contained directories, and then provide a single entry point to that library. There are three ways in which a folder may be passed to require() as an argument.

The first is to create a package.json file in the root of the folder, which specifies a main module. An example package.json file might look like this:

```
{ "name" : "some-library",
"main" : "./lib/some-library.js" }
```

If this was in a folder at ./some-library, then require('./some-library') would attempt to load ./some-library/lib/some-library.js.

This is the extent of Node's awareness of package.json files.

If there is no package.json file present in the directory, then node will attempt to load an index.js or index.node file out of that directory. For example, if there was no package.json file in the above example, then require('./some-library') would attempt to load:

./some-library/index.js
./some-library/index.node